# Parameters in a Priority Queue Constructor

Tags: java, priority-queue, comparator

Lately i have started to work with priority queues in java and i already found myself something which i don't seem to understand. I have used the comparator class to sort the priority queue in my way.

Here is a simple program which i did:-

```
package main;

import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

class PQ implements Comparator<Integer> {

  public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) { // sort in the descending order
    return o2 - o1;

  }
}

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] list = { 1, 5, 6, 9, 10, 3, 5, 2, 13, 15, 17, 19, 25, 1, 0 };
    PQ pqs = new PQ();

    PriorityQueue<Integer> pq1 = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(10, pqs);
    // what does this "10" parameter does?

    for (int x : list) {
      pq1.offer(x); // put values in to the queue
    }

    for (int x : list) {
      System.out.println(pq1.poll()); // pops out from the queue.
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is what does the integer parameter "10" means in the priority queue constructor?(Am passing it but i don't know what it does)

I searched the internet and found out that it is used to specify the initial capacity , but still am unable to understand it clearly.

Can anyone explain me what it does ?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the initial capacity of the 'PriorityQueue'.
When you have doubts like this you should refer to the [official documentation of the class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html).

It is used in cases you know in advance how much space you will need (At least at the beginning) so that the instantiated object can allocate enough memory to store that number of elements without having to waste time allocating a smaller amount of memory (To save space) and then spending some time to alloc new memory as it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

A [`PriorityQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) is backed by an `Object[]`. By default, this array will have a size of `11`, but it has to be resized (an `O(n)` operation) whenever you add more elements than it can hold. You are specifying the initial size of this array via the int constructor argument, presumably to avoid such resize operations:

```
147       public PriorityQueue(int initialCapacity,
148                            Comparator<? super E> comparator) {
149           // Note: This restriction of at least one is not actually needed,
150           // but continues for 1.5 compatibility
151           if (initialCapacity < 1)
152               throw new IllegalArgumentException();
153           this.queue = new Object[initialCapacity];  // <--
154           this.comparator = comparator;
155       }
```

([source](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.java.html))